# Unable to insert second element to a linked list | Pointer to function gets corrupted

Tags: c, linked-list

Bellow is the relevant code:

```
typedef struct Node_t {
    ListElement data;
    struct Node_t* next;
} Node;

struct List_t {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    Node* current;
    int size;
    CopyListElement copyF;
    FreeListElement freeF;
};
```

---

```
static ListResult initializeNode(List list, ListElement element, Node* newNode){
    printf("\nEntered initializeNode\n");
    if ((list == NULL) || (element == NULL)) return LIST_NULL_ARGUMENT;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newNode == NULL) return LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    printf("\nWithin initializeNode, before copyF\n");
    ListElement newElement = list->copyF(element);
    printf("\nWithin initializeNode, after copyF\n");
    if (newElement == NULL) return LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    newNode->data = newElement;
    printf("\nLast line within initializeNode\n");
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

```
List listCreate(CopyListElement copyElement, FreeListElement freeElement){

    //Check if there is a NULL argument.
    if ((copyElement == NULL) || (freeElement == NULL)) return NULL;

    //Check wether there is enough memory.
    List newList = malloc(sizeof(List));
    if (newList == NULL) return NULL;
    //Initialize an empty List.
    newList->head = NULL;
    newList->tail = NULL;
    newList->size = 0;
    newList->current = NULL;
    newList->copyF = copyElement;
    newList->freeF = freeElement;

    return newList;
}
```

---

```
ListResult listInsertFirst(List list, ListElement element){
    printf("\nEntered listInsertFirst\n");
    Node* newNode;
    ListResult result = initializeNode(list, element, newNode);
    printf("\n Node was initialized\n");
    if (result != LIST_SUCCESS) {
        return result;
    }

    printf("\nEntering logistic works within listInsertFirst\n");
    //Finish logistic work within the Node.
    newNode->next = list->head;
    list->head = newNode;
    list->size++;
    printf("\nElement was inserted successfully\n");

printf("\nCheck list->CopyF within listInsertFirst\n");
list->copyF(element);
printf("\nCheck list->CopyF within listInsertFirst: PASSED\n");

    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Within main function I'm trying:

```
List list = listCreate(&copyInt, &freeInt);

ListResult result;
int el=2;
//ListElement e1;
//ListElement e2;

result = listInsertFirst(list,&el);
printf("\nresult = %d\n", result);

result = listInsertFirst(list,&el);
printf("\nresult = %d\n", result);
```

---

> After compiling and running I get:
>
> Entered listInsertFirst
>
> Entered initializeNode
>
> Within initializeNode, before copyF
>
> Within initializeNode, after copyF
>
> Last line within initializeNode
>
> Node was initialized
>
> Entering logistic works within listInsertFirst
>
> Element was inserted successfully
>
> Check list->CopyF within listInsertFirst Segmentation fault: 11

For some reason the pointer [to function] list->copyF gets corrupted [I think].

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?  The first thing I would try is adding -Wall -Wextra.  Also, have you tried Valgrind?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is C code, not C++, based on the tags. Given that you have a mix of data definitions and actual code statements, which I wouldn't expect to work in C, I'm not 100% sure it is real C, in which case I may be wrong about the error below.

First of all, the interface to `initializeNode()` doesn't do what you probably intend. You probably want:

```
static ListResult initializeNode(List list, ListElement element, Node** newNodep)
{
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newNode == NULL) return LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    ListElement newElement = list->copyF(element);
    if (newElement == NULL) return LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    newNode->data = newElement;
    *newNodep = newNode;
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

That way the Node you create gets passed back.

I don't know what `CopyInt()` does, but if it's really the function hitting the Bus Error the bug with `initializeNode()` can't be your problem. However, it's possible that you aren't seeing the output of all your printfs before the crash gets reported.

If `CopyInt()` does what I'd expect, it does something like:

```
ListElement CopyInt(int *val)
{
    ListElement *e = malloc(sizeof(ListElement));
    if (e) 
        e->val = *val;
    return e;
}
```

The only way you are going to get a second-time bus error here is if you've messed up the data structures maintained by the library function `malloc()`. Unfortunately for that theory, I don't see anything worse than a memory leak here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it will take me some time to analyze it.
BTW, this is C99.

Comment: initializeNode get a pointer to a Node, so i don't think your fix for initializeNode is "good".

Answer (score 0):

My guess that the bug that actually causes the crash is this line:

`newNode->next = list->head;`

Like @Arlie Stephens said - code for `initializeNode` doesn't do anything as the pointer is passed by value and the actual pointer still points to junk. So when you do `newNode->next = list->head;` you're basically writing to an unknown address and it's very likely to get a segmentation fault.
Why does it only happens on the second call? No idea, it's undefined behavior.

Crazy idea - it's possible that newNode->next is initialized to the address of copyF and trying to write into it cause you to corrupt copyF...Try printing the address of newNode->next and the address of copyF.